# Where to put AuthorizeAttribute extended class in ASP.Net authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

When implementing authorization for ASP.NET, where should I put `AuthorizeAttribute` implemented class?

In my project, I have created a class called `BasicHttpAuthorizedAttribute` which implements `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` class and I have overridden the methods I want.

I have registered this `BasicHttpAuthorizedAttribute` class as a filter.

My problem is even though I do not mention the `[Authorized]` attribute on top of controller method, `BasicHttpAuthorizedAttribute` class's `OnAuthorization()` method gets called.

That should not be like that, right? It should only be called if you have mentioned `[Authorized]` attribute on top of controller method. Am I right?

What am I doing wrong here? (My project is a ASP.Net web api project and I am using `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute` class)

Comment: Because you've registered it as a filter, it will be called regardless.

Comment: @steen yes, so how should I add it?

Comment: Have a look at this swanky article which explains the uses and some tips and tricks: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it goes into the `OnAuthorization()` event each time because you've registered it as a filter.

This article has a few neat tips and trips on blanket filtering and anonymous exceptions, which is, I think, what you want. It may be for MVC, but the techniques used should apply to most ASP.NET types with a little tweaking.

> http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Example from article:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
```